# Expected ',' but got identifier

Tags: solidity

I am new in solidity and General with coding.
i use this : Truffle v5.5.21 (core: 5.5.21) ,Ganache v7.2.0,Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v12.22.12,Web3.js v1.7.4.

I took this error and i cant fix it. I checked more interesting information's about my project but the problem is problem...I would be grateful if I could have some help

(in terminal)
CompileError: test:/contracts/EmailRegex.sol:49:34: ParserError: Expected ',' but got identifier
cur = state(cur).func(uint c);

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

library EmailRegex {
  struct State {
    bool accepts;
    function (byte) internal pure returns (uint) func;
  }

  function state(uint  id) internal pure returns (State memory) {
    if (id == 1) {
      return State(false, s1);
    }
    if (id == 2) {
      return State(false, s2);
    }
    if (id == 3) {
      return State(false, s3);
    }
    if (id == 4) {
      return State(false, s4);
    }
    if (id == 5) {
      return State(false, s5);
    }
    if (id == 6) {
      return State(false, s6);
    }
    if (id == 7) {
      return State(false, s7);
    }
    if (id == 8) {
      return State(false, s8);
    }
    if (id == 9) {
      return State(true, s9);
    }
    if (id == 10) {
      return State(true, s10);
    }
  }

  function matches(string memory input) public pure returns (bool) {
    uint cur = 1;

    for (uint i = 0; i < bytes(input).length; i++) {
      uint8 c = uint8(bytes(input)[i]);

      cur = state(cur).func(uint c);
      if (cur == 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return state(cur).accepts;
  }

  function s1(uint8  c) internal pure returns (uint) {
    if (c == 37 || c == 43 || c == 45 || c == 46 || c == 57 || c >= 65 && c <= 90 || c == 95 || c >= 97 && c <= 122) {
      return 2;
    }

    return 0;
  }

  function s2(uint8  c)  internal pure  returns (uint) {
    if (c == 37 || c == 43 || c == 45 || c == 46 || c >= 48 && c <= 57 || c >= 65 && c <= 90 || c == 95 || c >= 97 && c <= 122) {
      return 3;
    }
    if (c == 64) {
      return 4;
    }

    return 0;
  }

  function s3(uint8  c)  internal pure returns (uint) {
    if (c == 37 || c == 43 || c == 45 || c == 46 || c >= 48 && c <= 57 || c >= 65 && c <= 90 || c == 95 || c >= 97 && c <= 122) {
      return 3;
    }
    if (c == 64) {
      return 4;
    }

    return 0;
  }

  function s4(uint8  c) internal pure returns (uint) {
    if (c >= 46 && c <= 47 || c >= 48 && c <= 57 || c >= 58 && c <= 64 || c >= 65 && c <= 90 || c >= 91 && c <= 95 || c >= 97 && c <= 122) {
      return 5;
    }

    return 0;
  }

  function s5(uint8  c) internal pure returns (uint) {
    if (c == 46) {
      return 6;
    }
    if (c == 47 || c >= 48 && c <= 57 || c >= 58 && c <= 64 || c >= 65 && c <= 90 || c >= 91 && c <= 95 || c >= 97 && c <= 122) {
      return 7;
    }

    return 0;
  }

  function s6(uint8  c) internal pure returns (uint) {
    if (c == 46) {
      return 6;
    }
    if (c == 47 || c >= 48 && c <= 57 || c >= 58 && c <= 64 || c >= 91 && c <= 95) {
      return 7;
    }
    if (c >= 65 && c <= 90 || c >= 97 && c <= 122) {
      return 8;
    }

    return 0;
  }

  function s7(uint8  c) internal pure returns (uint) {
    if (c == 46) {
      return 6;
    }
    if (c == 47 || c >= 48 && c <= 57 || c >= 58 && c <= 64 || c >= 65 && c <= 90 || c >= 91 && c <= 95 || c >= 97 && c <= 122) {
      return 7;
    }

    return 0;
  }

  function s8(uint8  c) internal pure returns (uint) {
    if (c == 46) {
      return 6;
    }
    if (c == 47 || c >= 48 && c <= 57 || c >= 58 && c <= 64 || c >= 91 && c <= 95) {
      return 7;
    }
    if (c >= 65 && c <= 90 || c >= 97 && c <= 122) {
      return 9;
    }

    return 0;
  }

  function s9(uint8  c) internal pure returns (uint) {
    if (c == 46) {
      return 6;
    }
    if (c == 47 || c >= 48 && c <= 57 || c >= 58 && c <= 64 || c >= 91 && c <= 95) {
      return 7;
    }
    if (c >= 65 && c <= 90 || c >= 97 && c <= 122) {
      return 10;
    }

    return 0;
  }

  function s10(uint8  c) internal pure returns (uint) {
    if (c == 46) {
      return 6;
    }
    if (c == 47 || c >= 48 && c <= 57 || c >= 58 && c <= 64 || c >= 91 && c <= 95) {
      return 7;
    }
    if (c >= 65 && c <= 90 || c >= 97 && c <= 122) {
      return 10;
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets see your code:

```
cur = state(cur).func(uint c);
```

You are defining the input variable inside the function parameter, you can't do that, try the following:

```
byte c; // remember to set the value you see fit.
cur = state(cur).func(c);
```

I suggest you also check the rest of your code, since for some reason, you're also defining c in this loop, and variables are only defined once, yet you can reassign its value later on.

```
for (uint i = 0; i < bytes(input).length; i++) {
  uint8 c = uint8(bytes(input)[i]);

  if (cur == 0) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Also, the interface for the function you specified on your struct's interface has a `byte` type input.

```
struct State {
    bool accepts;
    function (byte) internal pure returns (uint) func;
}
```

But, your sX functions has a `uint8` input type instead. This will also cause error's

Can't see any other issues so far, yet I haven't tried compiling it.

Comment: Im glad it helped :D, please mark my response as the solution so we can get this question closed :)